# Can I ask about assembly programming in the game "Human Resource Machine"?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Update**: The comments and answers here made me realize there's a more general question to be asked, so I [asked about video-game language questions in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280035/are-questions-about-programming-within-a-video-game-different-from-questions-a) on Meta.SE.

There's a Steam/iOS game called "[Human Resource Machine](https://tomorrowcorporation.com/humanresourcemachine)", where you solve levels and advance by programming in a proprietary assembly language.

The game is essentially an introduction to the fundamentals of programming, at the assembly level, aimed at novices, or kids, or OCD weirdos like me who are intrigued by the idea of making asm programming *fun* (weird thing is they did it).

Example screenshot: 
[image: screenshot of game]

The little guy is the ALU, the carpet is main memory, and the program is listed on the right.

I'd like to ask some questions about how to optimize certain solutions (effectively: briefer code or faster execution). Would these questions be welcome on SO?

It is programming, for sure, but I'm unsure about whether it's on-topic because it's not a "problem I face in real life", it's a video game.

I could ask on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), but the answers I'm looking for aren't "grind dire rats until you can upgrade to Excalibur", they're "you can save a JMP by checking for zero instead of negative, and here's a way to consolidate two variables and save memory".

<sub>**Please note**: "no" is a perfectly acceptable answer. I'll interpret any downvotes on this question as "no", upvotes as "sure". Vote away. You won't hurt my feelings.</sub>

<sub>Also, if anyone is active in the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) community, I'd also be interested in knowing whether HRM questions would be welcome or unwelcome there, as well, but I suppose here on Meta.SO, that information should be offered in the comments.</sub>

Comment: If you write the question that someone can understand and answer it without buying the game I think you can totally ask that question. Now if your code does not work I would ask on SO, while when you have working code and you want to optimize it you probably want to go to codereview. Also make sure to always include a screenshot when you solved the level after the question :)

Comment: Oh, that's something I hadn't considered: no one can *test their answers* without buying the game. Hmph. Let me think about that. And thanks for the note on broken : working :: SO :: CodeReview, that's an easy dividing line to remember.

Comment: That is an essential part that you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that *everyone* can "copy&paste" your code and sees what you get now and where you want to go.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yeah, for sure; most levels can be solved in 20 lines or fewer. I intend to provide them textually using the internal .asm format the game uses, [like in this GitHub](https://github.com/atesgoral/hrm-solutions/blob/master/solutions/10-Octoplier-Suite-9.36/9.36-atesgoral.asm) (not mine, and warning, repo is full of spoilers).

Comment: BTW, Arqade is made of programmers too. In fact, the thing was created shortly after (before) SOUF came into fruition.

Comment: @Braiam That's a fair point. Wish I'd thought to ask on Meta.SE about the most appropriate stack before I posted here.

Comment: Scratch and TIS-100 are on-topic here, I don't see why this wouldn't be on-topic as long as the question is clear and your "code" is added properly

Comment: @DanBron as for Code Review, [ask here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: As long as it works and you include your code in some useful form, it would definitely be on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Just because a question is about a commercial product shouldn't make it off topic.  There are lots of questions about proprietary tools that not everyone is going to be able to reproduce for free (e.g., any non-free compiler,  editor, etc. ).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That's a fair response to the doubt about "they have to buy the game to test their answers", for sure. Thanks. But what I'm more interested in is not whether the question should be treated differently because it's a "commercial product", but because it's a "video game": that is, the question, and answers, are "just for fun". If I never got an answer, no nuclear reactor would fail, no customer would be pissed, no boss would yell at me: it's not a *practical* problem.

Comment: @dan the site is for professional and enthusiast programmers.  You sound enthusiastic about this type of programing.  If the question is researched to the extent that makes sense, and written clearly, and your attempts are shown, I don't see much problem.  It's not going to be noise in another programming language's tag. I don't expect you'll get lots of attention or views, but that's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: You could ask at http://gaming.stackexchange.com too. There would be no question about this being on-topic there.

Comment: I _did_ expect this question on `meta` for quite a while. As HRM is called a game only by the fact it's distributed over Steam, I think it's totally valid to ask question on StackOverflow. Game mechanics is pretty simple to write a 100-line C program to emulate the game, so I don't think that "that's proprietary" is anywhere close to a valid point.

Comment: I love the fact there are -4 vote on this question...

Comment: @DanBron I started playing this game after seeing your question - thanks for the recommendation :) Just in case you didn't notice, there's a "copy" button at the bottom of the instruction list in the game. That'll give you a "pseudo assembly"-version of your program that'll work nicely in SO questions.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There are really two different questions here, one implicit and one explicit:

1. Implicit: Are questions about programming in the game "HRM" on-topic for Stack Overflow
2. Explicit: Are questions about *optimizing* "HRM" programs on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Some comments have stated that a requirement for being on-topic is that someone must be able to understand the question, run the code, reproduce a problem in the code, etc. without purchasing the game. But this is clearly incorrect. There are lots of proprietary programming environments which require purchase of tools, developer licensing fees, etc. to participate in, and questions about languages in those environments would still be on-topic here even if some or most of the community would have no way to validate the question, never mind answer it.

Just because all of the mainstream programming environments have moved to a "free" model, that doesn't mean there aren't any environments which aren't free, nor that non-free environments are in some way not still involved with programming or off-topic for Stack Overflow.

I also disagree that it is necessary that one be able to literally copy and paste via clipboard the text of a program from a Stack Overflow post into the programming environment. That's certainly desirable, and if the "HRM" game provides for that capability then of course a question asking for debugging help, etc. must include such a code example.

But if the programming environment itself does not allow copy/paste to work, that in and of itself would not disallow the question from Stack Overflow either. What's on topic depends on whether it involves *programming*, and whether there's a practical problem that can be solved. Whether the programming environment makes it easy to load arbitrary code into it is irrelevant (and again, while this isn't the case for mainstream programming environments, there certainly are real programming environments where copy/paste text doesn't work…look at, for example, MIT's [Scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch) programming language).

So where does that leave us answer-wise?

1. Questions about programming in the game "HRM" absolutely *can* be on-topic for Stack Overflow. They would still need to meet other criteria for being on-topic, but clearly you're dealing with a programming language in which specific, practical problems may need to be solved.
2. Questions about optimizing "HRM" programs may well *not* be on-topic for Stack Overflow, as such questions are generally considered more appropriate for Code Review. I.e. Stack Overflow is primarily for code that doesn't work, while Code Review is primarily for code that does. Now, I can't speak for the Code Review community in terms of what's on-topic there; it's possible questions about optimizing "HRM" programs would be off-topic there too. But it would not be because the question is about optimization, but rather for some other reason related to the language itself or the environment.

Comment: +1. To clarify, I'm on board with the idea of "questions about fixing broken code belong on SO, questions about optimizing working code should be directed to SR".  The main question here, I think, hinges on whether we consider "How do I advance in this video game?" to be a "practical" problem. Obviously I'm biased towards "yes", but I had a twinge of conscious about whether others would agree.

Comment: @Dan: given that SO happily fields homework questions and other questions that are clearly academic in nature (i.e. not literally "practical"), it's clear that SO has a fairly liberal understanding of the word "practical" in this context. I read the word to be referring as much or more to the _solution_ to the problem than the question itself, though both are important.

Comment: @Dan: e.g. someone trying to implement a Traveling Salesman algorithm is not really solving a "practical" problem in the literal sense, and if they asked for the _optimal_ solution, that would not be on-topic. But if they are exploring other solutions to the problem as an academic exercise, and have some _specific_ and _practical_ difficulty that can be answered in a way consistent with the general SO guidelines, then that question would still be on-topic, even though it has no real-world practical application in the literal sense.

Comment: @Dan: I'm sure if we look, we can find someone who would disagree. It's the Internet after all. But I think there's a good body of evidence to support yours and my understanding of the use of the word "practical" in this context.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm honestly really pleased you guys are cool with this. I didn't expect you would be.

Comment: For help minimising number of commands, you can also try [codegolf.se]

Comment: [Optimizing slow code is on topic on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review) Stack Overflow is not "primarily for code that doesn't work"; we are not a debugging service. We are a *programming question and answer site*.

Comment: @user2357112: you are nit-picking a straw man. I never said questions about optimizing are never on-topic on Stack Overflow. Just that they are typically more appropriate on Code Review (and I base this on the general way they are typically presented on SO). On SO, a question would need to provide a good MCVE, along with some _specific_ problem description the question author is attempting to solve. Most "optimization" questions on SO take more the form of "is there any way to improve my code?" and those are too broad, or even off-topic here (depending on specifics).

Comment: The game allows copy/pasting code. It's just plain Intel-like assembly with labels.

Comment: @user2357112 actually, you must specify which aspect of your code you want to optimize. A dump of "here's my code, optimize it" is very likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Braiam: A dump of "here's my code, what's wrong with it" without specific details about the problem would also be closed. Both debugging questions and optimization questions can be asked badly, and both are frequently closed for it. You can't just single out the bad optimization questions and use them to imply optimization is usually off topic, any more than you could do that for debugging questions.

Comment: @user2357112: you are missing the point. As I already said, nothing in my reply says that optimization questions are per se off-topic on Stack Overflow. Simply that most are asked in a way that makes them more appropriate for CR (i.e. broadly). You're arguing against a point that no one, least of all I, ever made.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: You heavily imply it, what with "Stack Overflow is primarily for code that doesn't work, while Code Review is primarily for code that does." If you mean "Stack Overflow requires specific questions, while Code Review accepts general requests for improvement", you should actually say something about that in your answer, rather than focusing on the working/not working distinction.

Comment: You literally don't say anything in the answer about the *way* in which optimization questions are asked, or what would make an optimization question on topic here.

Comment: @user2357112: _"You heavily imply it"_ -- quite the contrary. My use of the word _"primarily"_ clearly and idiomatically indicates that there are exceptions. The word is useless in a context where the intent is to describe something that is exclusively the case. _"Primarily"_ specifically and directly indicates exceptions do exist.

Comment: @user2357112: _"You literally don't say anything in the answer about the way in which optimization questions are asked"_ -- because that's not relevant to the question that is being answered. The goal is not to write entire treatises on a topic; rather, to simply and directly address the specific question asked. There's no need for me to go into additional detail, as it's reasonable to assume a person understands the difference between a question about optimization that's on-topic on Stack Overflow and one that's not. Stop making a mountain of a molehill.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: "it's reasonable to assume a person understands the difference between a question about optimization that's on-topic on Stack Overflow and one that's not" - unfortunately, such an assumption is not warranted. I care about this because I keep seeing people pushing away the on-topic, *good* optimization questions, treating the working/not working distinction as what makes a question suitable or unsuitable for Stack Overflow, rather than treating it as an indicator loosely correlated with on-topicness.

Comment: You're answering a question about what is on topic for Stack Overflow. The questioner would not *be* here if they were confident in what is or isn't on topic. An answer phrased in terms of working/not working promotes confusion about Stack Overflow's focus and makes yet more people think we're a debugging site.

Answer (score 12):

## Depends on the scope of the specific question

- If you need help with a specific aspect of the language or how to do something in it (e.g. "How do I add 2 numbers"<sup>[1]</sup>), the Stack Overflow is the best choice.
- If you need golfing (shorter code) then post to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf as a [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tips) question.
- If you need other optimization help, like speed, try Code Review. You may not get many reviews, but somebody might be able to help.

And yes, the *language* should be allowed on any of these sites, the question is just whether the *question* is on-topic.

Comment: [Peter's answer also helps explain why the language should be on-topic.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325701/5458362)

Comment: Thanks! The primary question is whether "the language should be allowed on any of these sites". I wanted to know whether the language, obviously artificial and impractical, disqualified questions about it. Clearly (I hope!) my questions will otherwise adhere to the protocols and norms of the specific sites. And if they don't, you guys better VtC. The key is whether if I asked the *exact same question* about x86, it would be welcome. (Though honestly I'd prefer x86, as much as it annoyed me in college, because at least it offers me *more than one $#^^~! register*!)

Comment: @DanBron okay? lol