# Please stop redirecting performance problems to Code Review

Tags: feature-request

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review), performance questions are valid on both sites. Nonetheless, I see again and again questions closed here for no reason other than that they contain some possibly working code.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57648218/581205) is clearly placed much better here. There's nothing to review (a few simple lines), the OP didn't ask for a review, there's hardly anything to improve besides performance. The code is [possibly buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648218/how-to-improve-performance-of-my-xml-parsing-code#comment101751147_57648218), and if so, then it definitely does not belong on CR.

What should the CR guys do with this question? Close it as it belongs to SO?

Please do something with this hot potato game. The OP needs to wait longer and there's one more useless question for no gain at all.

A [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/581205) asked for a deletion of CR-migration-related comments. I don't think, it's a good idea as this comment may be in the meantime answered and you lose context. Otherwise, someone else will probably post a similar comment soon.

Instead, I'd suggest something like follows:

- Add a warning when casting a close vote for questions tagged "performance" (such questions fall most often pray to migration closing). It should be just a small warning like "Note that performance questions are in general placed well on this site").
- Add a bigger warning when casting a close vote and there is (or was) a comment mentioning CR.

Comment: @Makoto No, this is no duplicate. I'm asking for stopping this nonsense completely. The other question asks for making some comments eligible for instant deletion, which may somewhat help with the hot potato problem, but I don't think it really does.

Comment: The accepted answer does seem to apply here. It is unrealistic to be able to completely prevent people from doing that.

Comment: @E_net4 Sure, there's no perfect solution, but there are quite a few things we could do and AFAIK we don't. I've read the accepted answer twice and I'm unsure if it answer *any* question (it's quite late here). ++ In case of the linked question, there's even a link to CR, so the poster could have been immediately informed about CR being no close reason at all. There's a "performance" tag, so any closer could have been shown a warning as I proposed. The question could be shown to some high-score reviewers, who could decide that a big red sign like "Before you vote to close...." should be shown.

Comment: It's not a hot potato game - it is dumb SO users who keep posting comments about "you should post this at CR" without knowing what's on topic on either site. Please flag such comments as "no longer needed", and that's that.

Comment: And I don't see how this meta post is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think a warning on close votes for the entire tag would be appropriate - for instance, the question you linked is clearly Too Broad regardless of whether it would fit on Code Review.

Comment: Was an attempt made to get this question migrated to CR? I don't see it in the timeline. Why would closing this question on SO cause a problem for CR, such that we'd need a warning when closing the question on SO? I could see *maybe* a warning if a closer asked for a custom migration to CR, but then, those involve a moderator. And that's one of the many reasons we have moderators -- to prevent us stupid users from making ill-informed migrations. Or is this just in response to a comment someone made about asking on CR? How is that relevant to the close dialog?

Comment: It doesn't seem lik ea duplicate to me; unless you have a previous feature-request asking for this same thing.

Comment: @Lundin The users are dumb or just new.... and there are tons of them, which means that the system itself is dumb or new. The system isn't new, so it's dumb. `+++` The two meta questions are surely related, but I'm asking for stopping users closing questions while Makoto's question asked for removing comments.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The OP has stated in the second (now deleted) comment that they reposted to CR (all migration-related comments were deleted). So this is at least as big a problem for CR as for SO (actually bigger since it's better placed here and since CR is much smaller). Involving the moderator means more work for them and that's something what could be handled by more experienced users alone (it's just about showing an additional warning, so there's no need for a big boss). `+++` The question was closed and reposted on CR - and this happens again and again.

Comment: I don't get what you are proposing - essentially stop closing questions tagged with "performance" whatsoever? The one you've linked to is perfect example of an awful performance question - "my code `MethodINotGoingToShow(42)` is slow. Fix it" - I don't see why it needs to stay open in current state nor I see good reasons why people suggest to move it to CR to help with perf part of the problem... Or is your suggestion to ask people to think/read guidance before providing random recommendations? (If you do have solution for that - share!).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No, I don't want such questions to be prevented from being closed, I only want them to be prevented from being closed for this wrong stupid reason. And even more I want them **not to be re-posted to CR**. And yes, I don't want to forbid closing, I only want to warn the closers in case they're probably wrong. I don't have any 100% solution (this would need an AI smarter than our users), but I guess, we could catch quite a few cases - without much programming effort and without bothering the users much.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think the question is awful. Imagine yourself having maybe one year programming experience, how would you write it better?

Comment: @maaartinus ohh… https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388868/is-it-good-idea-to-prevent-down-vote-on-new-contributor-status :) … Without putting any effort to investigate I would likely write awful question too... But why the fact user is new should change if question contains all necessary information or not/answerable?

Comment: @maaartinus for FR itself - I don't think suggesting CR is main (or even significant) problem with "performance" questions... If SO would consider more guidance based on tags in general your suggestion may be part of it, by itself it probably going to add more confusion than value... Especially if you see people with less than 3K rep commenting to post on CR - they won't even get warning you suggest as they are unlikely to close the post... Or if you vote "missing MCVE" and get "don't suggest CR" warning.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The problem with noobs is that they'd need to spend days investigating (and then, they may write a ten pages question containing their findings. No thanks). `+++` Downvoting is fine, closing is fine but only after providing some hints - "Too broad" is simply too broad and should be banned. If you treat SO as a growing archive, then OK, but for getting answers it became pretty unusable for beginners. `+++` Moreover, the question is only unanswerable because of being closed, by I guess, [I provided an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57648218/581205#comment101751147_57648218).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I may be wrong, but I read pretty all `[java] [performance]` questions and the CR nonsense comes again and again. It's not only about closing a question, but it's also about spamming a (smaller) site. In the end, there are two closed question, no answer and a doubly frustrated OP. Nice for the SO *archive* and stupid for anyone using SO actively.

Comment: @maaartinus I see - sounds java+perf has this problem while c#+perf does not... Maybe as alternative suggestion have usual regex-based warning for "comment contains CR|codereview and not {link to CR migration FAQ}"? That may be easier to implement and more likely actually have impact on those who comment...

Answer (score 9):

**Regarding incorrect comments about migration to CR**
 Simply flag them as "no longer needed". Respond to incorrect comments by posting the link 
[A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

**Regarding incorrect close votes about migration to CR**
Vote/flag for re-open. If you feel that the post isn't getting enough attention to swiftly get re-opened, visit the [SO Close Vote Review Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask for help there.

**Regarding performance questions being off-topic on SO**
They never were. The only case where such a question would be more suitable for CR is when the OP posts the complete code and asks an open-ended question about improvements, where it would be too broad for SO.

Most importantly, just because something is on-topic on another site, it doesn't automatically become off-topic on SO. Lots of sites have overlapping scopes.

Also keep in mind that some 9 out of 10 of performance problem questions we see on SO are "XY problems" where the true problem is incorrectly performed benchmarking. Such questions often need to include benchmarking information as part of the question to stay open on SO and should definitely not get migrated.

Comment: Do know that SOCVR has a [(lengthy) FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) that points out our rules.