# What's wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

What is wrong with my original question, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316525/alternate-way-to-get-html-content-from-webpage*?

I try to be direct and professional, and I get anonymous downvotes. Reddit already solved my problem, so I don't think the question is totally stupid.

I've seen many stupid questions on these sites, and they had more feedback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s

Comment: Probably because of links only and could have easily fit in a comment. Oh, and you were trying to reply.

Comment: How does my post fail in regards to that content? I feel I conformed pretty well.

Comment: I replied to it after getting down votes and finding help elsewhere.

Comment: **You reply in comments, not in the answers area.**

Comment: What is wrong with the original question?

Comment: Please do not compare Stack Overflow with Reddit. SO has higher standards of quality, and if a question does not show a clear purpose or is unlikely to be helpful for future visitors, then it may receive negative feedback.

Comment: Note that we are a LOT more strict than any webdev related subreddit. If it's open ended, or an opinion question, etc. - whatever relevant subreddit is a MUCH better place for those sorts of questions. We do questions that are more pointed and direct.

Comment: Wasnt the question pretty direct? I have seen horribly open ended questions get replies...

Comment: No one is answering why the original question is not valid. Is it not direct?

Comment: @Aaron, have you read the how-to-ask link I posted in my first comment? That will tell you of possible failings your question may have had; and would explain you how a question here is very different than a question to be posted at reddit or quora or anything like that.

Comment: No one can tell you why you were down-voted, because voting is anonymous and we are not mind-readers. But if you read the how-to-ask carefully, you may find ideas to improve the reception your question get.

Comment: I read it and feel confident i conformed. How does the question not conform to the material you provided?

Comment: Too much energy wasted on this. I solved my problem... Two of them it seems. See u when im a professional.

Comment: @Aaron I have added a comment to your question. Nevertheless, you should understand that we should not feel obliged to reply to "why the downvotes".

Comment: I would downvote too, although now I'm not going too. Your question is unanswerable - actually the two questions you're asking are unanswerable.  Just think about it: "Is 2 minutes typical for extracting 30 webpages' content?" - Yeah on a slow internet connection running on a Raspberry Pi Zero and with websites that are very large or have slow reaction times, sure. Too many variables.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Although the answer was jsoup library to first question.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic. There you go for another reason for possible downvotes.

Comment: Im trying to learn. What i learned was that this is not the place for me yet lololol ty for ur time all

Comment: Please use real words, you’ll find a better reception when you do. “u”, “ur”, “ty”, “lololol” all suggest you’re not taking it seriously, and people rightly object to that.

Comment: Can you post the reddit link for comparison?

Answer (score 30):

I'm *willing* to bet that most of the negative feedback came in after you posted your "answer":

[image]

But in all reality, there are things you could have done to solicit a better response from us.

- **Include the URL you're hitting, or if it's an inappropriate link, include a URL that exhibits the same issues.**  It's important for us to be able to reproduce your issue in order for us to help.
- **Be *patient*.**  You seem to have left in a bit of a huff after not getting an answer in two days, which while not unheard of, is fairly par for the course.
- **Profile your code on an individual effort.**  It's [important for you to show your work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286557/1079354) when you say you have "slow" code, and that means for you to profile it.  Try to discern what the slow points are on your own and then come to us with educated questions backed by facts in your own findings.  As pointed out in the comments, "slow" can be subjective depending on the hardware and internet connection you have.

Stack Overflow works like a two-way street.  You have to help us for us to be able to help you.  I don't think you were quite ready to go down that path, so I'm hoping you take this as an early "lesson learned" and not get too discouraged about it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to come back, while unfortunate in and of itself, hopefully wherever you wind up will still require you to show courtesy to potential answerers.

Comment: Im still here. Just focusing on learning not this stuff. I answered my own question after receiving all those downvotes.

Comment: @Aaron Treating downvotes as if they were a form of spite is inappropriate. You can read more about this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s). Even if you feel that you were insulted, it is not a reason to post non-answers and complain about the site.

Comment: The question asked for alt. Implementation that is faster than reading a stream. No on answered. Lots downvoted. There are many worse questions that get upvotes. I can connect the dots to observe inconsistency.

Comment: @Aaron You *didn't* answer to your question.  You posted an answer just to complain about the site.  That's not an answer, which is why it was deleted.

Comment: @Aaron The fact that there are worse questions out there doesn't mean yours was good.  Not every question can be *the worst* question out there, it doesn't mean they're all good just because they're not *the worst*.

Comment: Im asking what was wrong with orignal post. Talking about my subsequent answer is off topic

Comment: @Aaron Then why were [you talking about your subsequent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359498/whats-wrong-with-my-question#comment532923_359502)?  I was merely responding to your comment.

Comment: @Aaron I believe that we have provided enough feedback on your question by now. You have preferred to ignore us and delete your question. That is not consistent.

Comment: Goodbye this is not fostering learning or community. I am going to program and come back when im so pro no one can refute the validity of my questions. Ty for ur time

Comment: True that. At least you learned something @Aaron

Comment: @Aaron: "*I am going to program and come back when im so pro no one can refute the validity of my questions.*" That's not how SO works. If a high rep user had asked your question, and posted that "answer" in response, the community would have rejected it just as much as they did for you. Downvotes ***are not personal***.

Comment: @NicolBolas I just took that quote as meaning when they're a professional they'll have learned how to ask valid questions.