# Add a close reason for half-formed profiling questions and allow for gold-badge holders to instantly close as such

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

We have [existing precedence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286559/1079354) when it comes to profiling questions.

- If you have a question about the performance of your code, then you should profile it *first*.
- It should be a narrow use case which can be reproduced.
- If you're looking to just optimize your code, you need to have done your homework before asking; just getting started and pointing at This Thing™ which may be causing slowdowns in your application isn't good enough 'round here.

To that end, I propose the following close reason.

> Questions seeking help with **code optimization, speed-ups or memory utilization** should contain enough evidence, such as but not limited to profiling metrics, that the provided snippet is a strong culprit for poor performance.  Avoid posting **unproven or incomplete code**, and avoid making assumptions of the code itself.

My inspiration for this:  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51847128/1079354).  This question is asking a very narrow question, but the question itself is misguided; there's no demonstrable way that the number of Strings that they're creating in that fashion is causing increased memory usage.  <s>Requests</s><s>Pleas</s> Insistence that the OP actually profile their code as opposed to guessing has gotten us nowhere.

Gold badge holders are more than equipped to have encountered these scenarios prior, and would be expected to know (more than) a thing or two about misperformant code.

Comment: How often do you see such questions?

Comment: @AndrewMyers:  Often enough that it's not the *worst* thing in the world to give them some kind of lifeboat.  As opposed to us burning cycles on trying to get the OP to add more details or proof that the snippet that they're posting is really the culprit, and as opposed to us dealing with answerers making flat-out *guesses* as to the nature of the OP's memory usage, I'd rather simply head it off.  We have the tool set to do such a thing.

Comment: @Makoto I am not convinced regarding the instant closing for gold badge holders. What makes the difference from other close reasons, the similarity to duplicates respectively? In general I agree this would be good additional close reason, and clearer as the _Questions looking for debugging ..._ reason.

Comment: I hate those questions.  Many of them, I get an immediate smell that the design of the rest of the app - that which is not posted and  is probably causing 99.999% of the performance problems, is a huge pile of PHP :(

Comment: This can't go anywhere of course, you can't get them to add a close reason could only apply to [0.4% of all questions](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=performance).  Just write a [faq] that explains why such a question was closed as "too broad".  Strange ask btw, you know this.

Comment: @HansPassant:  That's curious - I didn't realize that the question I linked to was tagged [tag:performance].  I'd argue that this is less of a strange ask and more of a, "Hey, seriously, start trusting your community to moderate this quicker."

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Duplicate closure is rationalized by a gold-tag badge holder having the experience of coming across or encountering that question before, and knowing where the answer is on the site.  I rationalize this by a gold-tag badge holder having encountered problems of performance, and knowing how to diagnose, debug and triage them.  This is definitely different and distinct from your rudimentary debugging question, because the context in which the question is being asked is different; one assumes broken code, whereas the other *requires* working code.

Comment: @MartinJames I can <del>delete</del> handle php code until it's quite fast, I assure you.

Comment: That comment cast doubt on you taking this seriously but we have to assume good faith.  Add [performance] to the Ignored Tags section of your profile so you'll never have to look at them again.  If you run into one that is missing the tag then just add it.

Comment: What's wrong with VTC as `unclear what you're asking: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.`? You can always add a comment to clarify further your reason.

Comment: @jpp:  Not only is it not quick enough, it's not useful enough to the standard OP.  "What more do I need to say?  My code is slow and I want help to make it fast!"  This close reason narrows the living heck out of such a request and says, "If you really want to make it fast, you're going to need to have done at least a little bit of your own research first to prove that this is *really* the part of your code that's painfully slow."

Comment: @HansPassant:  I'm taking this quite seriously.  I was merely adding a counterargument to your point - not all questions like this are tagged "appropriately".  I would edit the tag in but I'm reluctant to given that I don't like editing questions which I don't believe have much of a chance in their current state.

Comment: @HansPassant:  Besides, it really doesn't do anyone any favors to simply ignore them.

Comment: You just want to complain about questions you don't like and, for some unguessable reason, read anyway.  Got it.  Stop punishing yourself to get ahead, [performance] does not need your help.  Answer rate is no worse than [java], *very* healthy voting in that community.

Comment: How is this *not* covered by just using a custom reason (which you can easily [auto-fill with a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se))? What percentage of to-be-closed questions do you think would use this reason? Is that percentage *really* sufficient to justify having this as a select-able close reason?

Comment: I seem to recall that there is a maximum number of off-topic reasons available in the close-dialog, and that SO is already at the maximum. What off-topic close reason do you propose is removed in order to replace it with this one?

Comment: Something something welcoming :P

Comment: Are you sure this is really a profiling question and not a "just curious how Java stores constants in memory" question?

Comment: If I may... That was a legitimate question. There is nothing on google that answers my question. And you want me to test it myself before asking? Then there is no need to ask. Everyone would just keep testing their code till they get the answer. All the questions like how to make get request, where to prefer ArrayList vs LinkedList, etc. All of them can be answered.... you guessed it right... by testing yourself!  @Makoto

Comment: Everyone who is in agreement that my question was not tested enough (or researched enough) before posting the question. What kind of question do you want people to ask?

Comment: @FarazDurrani mm, I had a feeling you were really asking an "ArrayList" vs "LinkedList" question, I'm curious as to why others interpreted this as "profiling" and stuck with it even when the OP replied; it kind of struck me as a conceptual question as to how Java works (I've seen many of these sort of questions in the .NET tags). I'd recommend posting an answer to this meta post. Maybe there's an edit that can be made to make your intent clearer but as far as I can tell the only thing you did "wrong" was use the word "memory". An unfortunate situation.

Comment: @Makyen SU/SF ones should be merged and reworded.

Comment: @Makato: I don't exactly see what's so bad about the example question or why you think that this is a profiling issue at all. For me, this asks how string constants are handled by the compiler/runtime and if there is an optimization that handles string constants with the same content. And even if it would be a profiling question, it is definitely not unclear what op is asking, so why close-voting with that reason?

Comment: @Makyen:  Analogous to my earlier comment, custom reasons aren't sufficient enough to cover this case.   They're not entirely immediate and they don't provide enough "This is *precisely* what is wrong with your question *and* here's how to fix it".

Comment: @Makyen:  It's still a fairly niche category on SO; I'll give you that for free.  But *because* it's fairly niche we can actually provide exact and specific advice for would-be OPs who have a question about their code which would beg to be profiled *before* a question is asked.

Comment: @BDL:  It's unclear to me what was meant by memory footprint because there's no specification around how much memory is available to the OP, or if they're running into an active scenario in which their application is running out of memory and they've managed to trace it down to those 500 constants.  Effectively, I'm not sure if the question the OP is asking is answerable by us since there are too many variables.  We can take stabs and guesses in the dark, but what value is that if someone later comes along and takes an answer there as gospel?

Comment: @jrh:  I'd have let it go if the question really were about how constants are stored in memory.  However, the question as posed gives too specific of a use case to be simply about that.

Comment: @FarazDurrani:  What's wrong with testing it yourself?  You're closer to the problem space than any stranger on the Internet, and you have an acute understanding of the memory constraints of your application.  Why is that such a bad thing?

Comment: @Makoto: "*there's no specification around how much memory is available to the OP, or if they're running into an active scenario in which their application is running out of memory and they've managed to trace it down to those 500 constants.*" It seems to me that you're trying to get enough information to know whether the asker ought to care or not. But that's ultimately irrelevant to the question itself. It doesn't matter if the OP is running out of memory and they've figured out that this is the reason why. What matters is the information they want to know.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Do you mean like...a trivia-style question then?  Just so I'm on the same page with you.

Comment: @Makoto: I don't know what you mean by "trivia-style question". My point is that the motives for the question aren't all that important. And text spent proving to you that they have isolated the specific performance issue they're running into is wasted space in terms of providing information that is necessary for answering the question. Knowing "how much memory is available" will not in any way change what you tell them about how much memory these strings take up.

Comment: What I'm getting at is @NicolBolas, you're comfortable with an OP asking a performance question that's not based in an actual, real-world context, and may be entirely hypothetical in nature?  How is proof of isolating the problem wasted space?  Why are you making assumptions of their server stack?  Some people still have 1GB servers that they run their applications on and that's a significant detail to include.

Comment: @Makoto: What I (and I guess NicolBolas) are trying to say is: Why does it matter out of which reason op asks the question? Even if the question is asked out of plain curiosity and with no real background behind it, would it change the answer how strings constants are stored in a binary or how they are loaded? The motiviation for questions should almost never influence if they on-topic (maybe except for XY-problems where what op asks is blantly nonsense, but that isn't the case here)

Comment: @Makoto answering for myself (but I'm pretty sure Nicol would agree): *"you're comfortable with an OP asking a performance question that's not based in an actual, real-world context, and may be entirely hypothetical in nature?"* - yes. *"How is proof of isolating the problem wasted space?"* - because it doesn't alter what the correct answer is, so is of not interest to an answerer or a reader with the same question. *"Why are you making assumptions of their server stack?"* - huh? He isn't. He's saying, pretty explicitly, that the stack is irrelevant to the specific question that was asked.

Comment: @Makoto If hypothetically this was what the OP was asking for (to me it seems like this is what the OP meant based on how the post is worded, and their responses, in the post itself and this meta comments section), how should the OP reword the post to make it clear that they are really looking for how constants are stored in memory? (Note: this would certainly be a Java implementation detail, though IMO an interesting one)

Comment: @Makoto: "*Why are you making assumptions of their server stack? Some people still have 1GB servers that they run their applications on and that's a significant detail to include.*" How exactly would that change your answer? How does it affect Java's memory management of such strings? The only way I can see it affecting the answer is if it makes you say "it's too little for you to care about." Which is a judgment call for the OP to make, not the answerer.

Comment: FWIW, as a reader I like digging into .NET's implementation details just for laughs and I'm always interested in "this is how the C# compiler interprets this statement / this is how the CLR implements this feature" posts; I'd definitely find the .NET equivalent of this Java post interesting and possibly a good starting point / hint for digging into parts of Roslyn (the compiler package) that I might not have touched yet.

Comment: @Makoto there is nothing wrong with it. Okay let's say I did run the test, and found out that x approach is better than y because x is taking more memory. But, how about concepts? How will I learn that? If I post a question here, somebody might tell me that x is bad because of such and such thing in your code initializing x times. etc.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that we should have a close reason for questions of this sort. But I disagree that we should allow gold badge holders the power to do so unilaterally.

This kind of closure is ultimately no different from the "lacks MCVE" or "typo" forms of "off-topic". So if we don't think that gold badge holders should be able to unilaterally close those, then they shouldn't be able to unilaterally close these either. And vice-versa.

The Dupe-hammer is justified, not by expertise in skill on a topic, but by expertise in a tag on Stack Overflow. That is, you've provided enough answers on a tag that you know how that tag works, where the duplicates are, and therefore can be expected to correctly diagnose them when you see one.

That's not the case here. To deal with performance problems, you need expertise in the topics of profiling and optimization. Those are different skills from knowing where the duplicates are.

Comment: *This kind of closure is ultimately no different from the "lacks MCVE" or "typo" forms of "off-topic".* I think we are way too late not giving gold badge holders the ability to close questions with these reasons already.

Comment: @Braiam Eh. I can see that both ways, to be honest. On the one hand, I frequently feel like really obviously garbage questions just don't get the eyeballs needed to clear them away. On the *other* hand, there are plenty of very trigger-happy close-voters, some of them gold badgers, who I wouldn't want let loose with an all-purpose closehammer, gleefully closing everything that didn't perfectly meet their personal standards. The requirement to get 4 votes of agreement is an important limitation on the power of a single person to shut down valuable Q&A; on balance, I would not want to lose it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that gold-badge holders *aren't* experts in some capacity?

Comment: @Makoto: I'm suggesting that holding a gold-badge is not proof of expertise in a topic. It *certainly* isn't proof of temperance. The only thing I would say that it "proves" is experience in the questions and answers on a particular tag on SO.

Comment: @MarkAmery well, luckily for us, the only tags with gold tag badge holders are the most popular, which also makes it more likely that there are others users that can speak out when something is not optimal.

Comment: @Braiam: "*the only tags with gold tag badge holders are the most popular*" Untrue. [tag:lua] is hardly popular, but it has 4 gold badge holders. [tag:glsl] and [tag:shader] both have one: *me*. And while the latter two are often combined with other tags, my point stands: in many relatively non-popular tags, it would not be difficult for a small cabal with complete close-voting power to decide what questions are and are not allowed in the tag.

Comment: "lua" "hardly popular", lets see: 14,416 questions, 20,561 answers, 6,236 answerers, only 22% unanswered. glsl and shader have respectively 2,265 and 2,464. That's enough users to put you in your place if you abuse your power. You don't need a hammer to confront a hammer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very much against this - not just the power being granted to gold badge holders, but the close reason you propose existing at all.

It's true that misguided "which is faster" questions get posted frequently. But demanding more "complete" examples and profiler output is an awful solution.

For one thing, it's unclear to me what you think sufficiently "complete" code looks like. Presumably you don't want askers to dump the entire code of their applications. But what, then? If what I'm ultimately trying to do is decrease the memory usage of my 100000-line program, and I've got some narrow and specific question that would aid me in doing so, how much context am I meant to provide? After reading your question here, I don't have a clue what you actually want. Anyone reading your proposed close reason is going to be left in a similar state of doubt. And they're going to be justifiably *pissed* when they dump their entire 600 line script to satisfy your demand that they not provide "incomplete" code, only to then have their question reclosed for lacking an MCVE on the basis that the code is no longer minimal.

For another thing, an asker may not *have* an application to profile yet. Maybe they're asking a question because the answer will inform a design choice they have to make. That's still legit.

But most importantly, application-specific code and profiling data is typically going to be useless noise to all future readers of the question, and indeed to its answerers. If the asker is right that finding a faster way to qux the baz is the specific thing they need to do to speed up their application, then useful answers are going to have to provide a faster way to qux the baz, whether profiling information is provided or not. That's certainly the only thing that future readers arriving at the "How can I qux the baz faster?" question are going to be interested in. As far as I can tell from your question, the *only* reason you want to demand this information is to judge whether an asker has "done their homework" before asking (your words!) and punish them with closure if they haven't.

This is not how question closure should work. If quxing the baz performantly is something that might be useful to some people, then a question about performant baz-quxing is fine. If the *particular user* who asked it happened to not really need a more performant baz-quxer, that's entirely *their* problem. It has no bearing on whether the question is on-topic. Whether a question should remain open should depend upon its answerability and its usefulness to future readers, but it should not depend upon what some high-rep users think they can infer from it about the competence and diligence of the asker. And we should *definitely* not be demanding large dumps of information be added to questions that serve no purpose for anyone but close-voting gatekeepers, while not influencing the answers to the question one iota and polluting it with noise to the detriment of every single future reader. At the point that we start doing that, the closure system turns into a force that actively makes questions worse. Askers should be adding information to their questions to make them more *useful*; at the point that they're instead being forced to add information purely to demonstrate their moral worthiness to ask their question, something has gone badly wrong.

Let's consider your own choice of example at [static variables memory footprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51847128/1709587), which asks whether the Java compiler will create one or many instances of a string constant repeated across multiple classes (and therefore whether we pay roughly 1x the string's length or roughly *n*x the string's length as the memory cost of using it as a constant in *n* classes). It is, to my eyes, a perfectly fine question as it stands (albeit with a classically unclear title). It's interesting, it's answerable, and I can just about conceive of a context where it would be an important performance consideration, like using a code generation tool that generates large numbers of classes (the asker suggests 500) all containing the same large string constant, for use in a memory-constrained environment.

Is that the context the asker is in? Does he have another good reason for asking? Or is he an idiot? I don't know, but more importantly, I don't see why it matters.

By all means point out in a comment that this particular performance consideration simply isn't going to matter in most contexts. But why close it? What *purpose* does that serve?

Comment: I'll clarify my scope in the question above, but I would argue that it's fairly self-explanatory.  You don't ever take on a 100,000 line program and try to find performance issues without doing *some* kind of triage on it.  There's no reason not to expect that of askers here and now.  I'm still thinking about the profiler metrics since they can actually be useful (I'm thinking of some performance issues I had with Python a long time ago in which I *did* use a profiler output as not noise).

Comment: Additionally, I take strong umbrage to this being a "perfectly fine question".  I can't replicate the environment that the OP is in since I don't have 500 classes readily loaded in a classpath to profile on their behalf.

Comment: @Makoto What would you advocate to make it replicable, then? A code-generation script (written in what language?) that will produce 500 class files? Leaving that up to the answerer to create, *if* they want to, seems entirely fine to me. An answerer may not need to replicate the environment anyway, since they may be able to cite official documentation rather than determining the answer empirically.

Comment: You're proving my point - this isn't a question we should be answering since the OP is far closer to the actual context than we are.  Asking them to replicate the environment so that we can do their profiling *on their behalf* is a fool's errand.  There are some questions which we probably shouldn't be answering, no matter the intentions on either side of the fence.  I'm only trying to make that explicit.

Comment: @Makoto I disagree entirely. The environment is replicable as it stands - the answerer just needs to write a script that creates 500 class files - and *doesn't need replicating in the first place* because this is a theoretical question that doesn't *actually* need 500 class files to test out. And all that aside, you keep talking about the OP's environment as if he actually has an existing codebase containing 500 classes with identical string constants, when you have no reason at all to think that. I strongly suspect the precise scenario presented by the asker is hypothetical.