# What to do after editing to be specific my closed as too broad question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

I have had only one question so far which got one downvote and got closed as too broad. This one is an old question of mine, it also has an answer which helped me further dig into the problem and I accepted it. Out of my habit to keep my record clean I decided to edit it to be more in line with what Stack Overflow likes.

So I edited this question, and I am a bit confident on it being on track for what Stack Overflow considers a good question. Then I cast a reopen vote. But I doubt anyone even looked at it. Or may be my edit was not on point?

Here is the question. [How to speed up this curl script for scrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071105/how-to-speed-up-this-curl-script-for-scrapping)

Can someone experienced please have a look and let me know what else can I improve here ?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286559/1079354

Comment: @Makoto thanks, that is relevant and i have already applied what you have posted in that answer. My question has complete code snipped to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I didn't notice any measurements or metrics to indicate where you think the actual sore points are.  An answer describes that it could be that you're reading the sites in serial, but their guess is as good as any since we don't have insight into what is poorly performing.  You have to **profile your code** before a question like this could make real sense.